# GitEye won't show changes

Tags: git, github, version-control, giteye

Using GitEye:

I have cloned my existing repository down from GitHub, to
... git / Android.Project

Using File Manager
I have copied the updated files from my working directory ...
... Projects / Android.Project
to
... git / Android.Project

My working directory does not have a .git file in it, so it is not being overwritten.

Using GitEye:

I tried dragging the files from the Working Tree Files view to the Staged Changes view, and am unsuccessful.

I am not attempting to commit and push the changes back to GitHub, and get the eror, "There are no staged Files"

Using CLI:

> cd git / Android.Project
> git status

[List of modified and untracked files appears .... YAY!!!!]

> git commit -a -m"Many Changes"

15 files changed, 1121 insertions(+), 410 deletions(-)

> git status

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

> git add -A
> git commit -a -m"resource images"
>
> git status

On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working directory clean

> git remote -v

origin https://github.com/enetarch/Android.Todo.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/enetarch/Android.Todo.git (push)

> git push origin master

Counting objects: 83, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (51/51), done.
Writing objects: 100% (57/57), 49.92 KiB, done.
Total 57 (delta 24), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/enetarch/Android.Todo.git
ad6e5a9..047bb32  master -> master

So, I did all that through the CLI, why couldn't GitEye do this?

Back in GitEye
I request to see the latest GIT commits and can see what I committed through CLI git.

So, any thoughts as to why this isn't working the way I expect it to?

Pardon the formatting issues, apparently StackOverflow doesn't like CLI copy/pastes

Answer (score 6):

Well try this:

*Window > Preferences > General > Workspace*. In the right pane select **"Refresh using native hooks or polling"**. Restart GitEye.

Now make changes to any file, switch to GitEye and give it a couple of seconds. The changed files will appear automatically in **Git Files/Git Staging** view.

**Version**: GitEye (Linux 64-bit) version 4.6.0.1.  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZwre.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You may be seeing a situation similar to the one I regularly face with GitEye.  Changed files don't immediately appear in the **Git Files** view.  I force the listing to refresh by choosing any other option from the pop-up menu of filtering options.  This is the control just above the **Working Tree Files** listing.

Usually, I'm in the "Show Pending" listing so I change to something like "Show Clean."  Then I change back to "Show Pending" and my changed files usually show up then.

**UPDATE:**  As it turns out this is probably the result of a recognized bug by the Egit team, and it has been addressed.

**Forum post:**  [EGit keeps showing CVS files in Unstaged/Staged view](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1081338&goto=1743841&#msg_1743841)

**Bug:**  [CVS directories are erroneously shown as deleted in staging view and commit dialog](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=478148)

As near as I can tell upgrading to GitEye version 2.0 has taken care of the issue for me.

Comment: This solution works but it sucks. I'm going back to SourceTree again.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree.  In fact, I consider the Git Files view to be broken in general.  A number of my repos are completely ignored by the view.  I've opted instead for using the similar Git Staging view.

Comment: It may also be the case that the global ignore file is not being loaded by GitEye.  I've used a few applications that don't seem to follow the convention the command line application uses for locating an ignore file.  I explicitly pointed GitEye to the same global ignore file that the command line uses because the Git Staging view started having problems.  It was showing a different list of changes than the command line would.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to steal3rd's answer, there is a refresh button hidden into the Git Repositories view:

[image]